# TextField.appendText on empty string or TextField.replacetext is not displayed

Tags: textfield, flashdevelop

I have a question:
when I use TextField.appendText( ) on a TExtField whos text is empty ( "" ), or TextField.replaceText( 0, text.length, "some text" ), the text is not displayed, but the text property is changed properly. Anyone has any idea as to why?

example:

```
_textField.replaceText( 0, _textField.text.length, String.fromCharCode( ke.charCode ) );    //if it is the first key, we replace the text, otherwise append to it
```

Gr, GP

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I need to use _textField.setSelection first =o